# How to rotate an image when reaching the footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navigation arrow on this website http://samverdycktest.be/marcuscatering/index-nl.html which I want to rotate so it points to the top when it reached the footer.
And it then ofcourse has to scroll back upfront when clicked on.

The arrow has already a scrolling effect on it, but I didn't figure out yet how to rotate elements and change the scrolling effect when reaching certain points at a website.

This is de link/arrow element:

```
<a href="footer" class="to-the-bottom">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-bottom"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below, I have used just JavaScript instead of JQuery in case you are not using the JQuery library.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1e1mp23u/3/)

**HTML**

```
<i id="icon" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-bottom"></i>
```

**JS**

```
// function to detect when scroollbar reaches the bottom of page
var whenScrlBottom = function() {
  // http://coursesweb.net/javascript/
  var win_h = (self.innerHeight) ? self.innerHeight : document.body.clientHeight;    // gets window height

  // gets current vertical scrollbar position
  var scrl_pos = window.pageYOffset ? window.pageYOffset : document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;

  // if scrollbar reaces to bottom
  if (document.body.scrollHeight <= (scrl_pos + win_h)) {
    //alert('Bottom');
    var d = document.getElementById("icon");
    d.className = d.className + " rotated";
  }

    else {
        var e = document.getElementById("icon");
        e.className = "fa fa-arrow-circle-o-bottom";        
    }
}


// register event on scrollbar
window.onscroll = whenScrlBottom;


var smooth_scroll_to = function(element, target, duration) {
    target = Math.round(target);
    duration = Math.round(duration);
    if (duration < 0) {
        return Promise.reject("bad duration");
    }
    if (duration === 0) {
        element.scrollTop = target;
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    var start_time = Date.now();
    var end_time = start_time + duration;

    var start_top = element.scrollTop;
    var distance = target - start_top;

    // based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep
    var smooth_step = function(start, end, point) {
        if(point <= start) { return 0; }
        if(point >= end) { return 1; }
        var x = (point - start) / (end - start); // interpolation
        return x*x*(3 - 2*x);
    }

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // This is to keep track of where the element's scrollTop is
        // supposed to be, based on what we're doing
        var previous_top = element.scrollTop;

        // This is like a think function from a game loop
        var scroll_frame = function() {
            if(element.scrollTop != previous_top) {
                reject("interrupted");
                return;
            }

            // set the scrollTop for this frame
            var now = Date.now();
            var point = smooth_step(start_time, end_time, now);
            var frameTop = Math.round(start_top + (distance * point));
            element.scrollTop = frameTop;

            // check if we're done!
            if(now >= end_time) {
                resolve();
                return;
            }

            // If we were supposed to scroll but didn't, then we
            // probably hit the limit, so consider it done; not
            // interrupted.
            if(element.scrollTop === previous_top
                && element.scrollTop !== frameTop) {
                resolve();
                return;
            }
            previous_top = element.scrollTop;

            // schedule next frame for execution
            setTimeout(scroll_frame, 0);
        }

        // boostrap the animation process
        setTimeout(scroll_frame, 0);
    });
}

function scroll_up() {
    var el = document.querySelector('body');
    smooth_scroll_to(el, el.scrollTop - 2000, 600);
}

var myEl = document.getElementById("icon");

myEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
    scroll_up();
}, false);
```

Comment: Did you include the code to scroll up when you click on the rotated arrow? Because that's not working yet

Comment: no doesn't work, I get this error in the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: scrollUp is not defined

Comment: @SamVerdyck I have removed the onClick event from the <i> tag as I used it in another attempt. Check the updated fiddle

Comment: still not moving. maybe there is a conflict with some other elements? I uploaded the updated site: http://samverdycktest.be/marcuscatering/index-nl.html

Comment: You must have something scrolling it down, as when I click it goes down. The reason it is not taking you up because something is overriding it to take the page down